# Not getting correct size of UILabel on landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` and I am getting it's size and height when my device is in landscape right mode. I am using `Autolayout` and also correct layout programmatically for device orientation. I fixed my label height and width using constraints but I am getting wrong height. I am very much confused.

```
// Height is 21 and is fixed but I am getting 4 here.
NSLog(@"Password Label height is %f", _passwordLabel.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: have set any other constrains to that label ?

Comment: Yes. I set other constraints.

Comment: can you give detail for those?

Comment: I removed all constraints bit getting same result.

Comment: In portrait mode, I get correct height, but in landscape mode, I get wrong height. May be it is because of AutoLayout.

Comment: just control-drag from the label to the label itself, and add height as a constraint

Comment: share your full view, I'll tell you what constraints to use

Comment: Where you check this height? In which method?

Comment: try to check not in viewDidLoad method.Try in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are check your constraint relation equal that use below code but doesn't equal that set equal.

or

Create constraint object and set height. for example:

```
lblHeight.constant = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Fixed Height, then try **not** to give **Aspect Ratio** constraint.

Only **Fixed Width** and **Fixed Height** constraints are enough.

Give label a background color and check it on Preview mode in IB for all devices and orientations.